# Import Error: geopandas fiona or pyogorio package using conda/jupyterlab

Tags: python, conda, geopandas

I'm trying to follow the GEDI remote sensing data tutorial here: https://git.earthdata.nasa.gov/projects/LPDUR/repos/gedi-V2-tutorials/browse/GEDI_L2B_V2_Tutorial.ipynb.

I used conda in my command prompt window to install packages and set up a Juptyerlab notebook using the following code:

```
conda create --name gedi python=3.9
conda activate geditutorial
conda install -c conda-forge geoviews=1.9.6
conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas=0.12.2
conda install -c conda-forge h5py=3.8.0
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab=3.5.3
```

When I get to "In [22]: Import a GeoJSON of Redwood National Park as an additional GeoDataFrame", I get the following error:

```
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 redwoodNP = gp.GeoDataFrame.from_file('RedwoodNP.geojson')  # Import GeoJSON as GeoDataFrame

File ~\anaconda3\envs\geditutorial\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py:556, in GeoDataFrame.from_file(cls, filename, **kwargs)
    507 @classmethod
    508 def from_file(cls, filename, **kwargs):
    509     """Alternate constructor to create a ``GeoDataFrame`` from a file.
    510 
    511     It is recommended to use :func:`geopandas.read_file` instead.
   (...)
    554 
    555     """
--> 556     return geopandas.io.file._read_file(filename, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\geditutorial\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py:242, in _read_file(filename, bbox, mask, rows, engine, **kwargs)
    172 def _read_file(filename, bbox=None, mask=None, rows=None, engine=None, **kwargs):
    173     """
    174     Returns a GeoDataFrame from a file or URL.
    175 
   (...)
    240     by using the encoding keyword parameter, e.g. ``encoding='utf-8'``.
    241     """
--> 242     engine = _check_engine(engine, "'read_file' function")
    244     filename = _expand_user(filename)
    246     from_bytes = False

File ~\anaconda3\envs\geditutorial\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py:112, in _check_engine(engine, func)
    110     _check_pyogrio(func)
    111 elif engine is None:
--> 112     raise ImportError(
    113         f"The {func} requires the 'pyogrio' or 'fiona' package, "
    114         "but neither is installed or imports correctly."
    115         f"\nImporting fiona resulted in: {fiona_import_error}"
    116         f"\nImporting pyogrio resulted in: {pyogrio_import_error}"
    117     )
    119 return engine

ImportError: The 'read_file' function requires the 'pyogrio' or 'fiona' package, but neither is installed or imports correctly.
Importing fiona resulted in: DLL load failed while importing _env: The specified procedure could not be found.
Importing pyogrio resulted in: No module named 'pyogrio'
```

I tried installing pyogrio and fiona using conda, but got errors about package directories:

```
  File "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1238, in print_unexpected_error_report
    message_builder.append(get_main_info_str(error_report['conda_info']))
  File "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 236, in get_main_info_str
    info_dict['_' + key] = ('\n' + 26 * ' ').join(info_dict[key])
KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs'
```

I'm super new to remote sensing, Python, and command line in general, so any help getting fiona or pyogrio to install so I don't get this error would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

solved! I rebuilt my conda environment and installed fiona and pyogrio using conda-forge before installing any other packages and it worked.